# How do I close a window that was opened with a .hta from the command line? (not manually)

Tags: windows, hta

Say I give the command test.hta

A window pops up displaying the page. How do I close that window from the command line? I can't do it manually because I'm not present. It's a batch script running.

Comment: [close method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536367(v=vs.85).aspx) ?

Comment: @SearchAndResQ Thanks for the link. I tried it and it didn't work, but I was doing it the wrong way. I copied the code in the link and now it works. Great! :)

Answer (score 2):

The commenter above helped me solve the issue. It can be done by the jscript code in the .hta file. Here is the pattern:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myclose()
    {
        close();
    }
    setTimeout(myclose, 3000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
The Sun is shining down on you today :)
</body>
</html>
```